# How to send external event via send-event.pl script?

Tags: opennms

I want to send the external event through *send-event.pl* script. I can send the event but getting an event such as "An event with no matching configuration...". Can you give me an IDEA to resolve this?***

Please find the info below what I have tried:

```
send-event.pl uei.opennms.org/vendor/traps/Down -x 5 -p 'Type 1' -p 'Down 0'
```

Do I need to mention OID too?

Here is the event info for your reference:

```
<event>
        <mask>
                <maskelement>
                        <mename>id</mename>
                        <mevalue>.1..9.8.9.9.0.1.1</mevalue>
                </maskelement>
                <maskelement>
                        <mename>generic</mename>
                        <mevalue>6</mevalue>
                </maskelement>
                <maskelement>
                        <mename>specific</mename>
                        <mevalue>2</mevalue>
                </maskelement>
        </mask>
        <uei>uei.opennms.org/vendor/traps/Down</uei>
        <event-label>...</event-label>
        <descr>...</descr>
                <logmsg dest='logndisplay'><p> 
                        Down trap received 
                        Type=%parm[#1]% 
                        Down=%parm[#2]%</p> 
                </logmsg>
        <severity>Minor</severity>
</event>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I have finally got the IDEA. I have missed to add object id with the object name. 

Please find the solution below,
```

**send-event.pl 
uei.opennms.org/vendor/traps/Down 
-p 'Type.1.9.8.9.9.0.1.1.0 1' 
-p 'Down.10.1.9.8.9.9.0.1.1.1 0'**

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$OPENNMS_HOME/bin/send-trap.pl uei.opennms.org/vendor/traps/Down
```

Comment: Thanks Mohamed & Marwie. Yeah, this is one of the way we can send some standard event. we have to specify the object id with object name if we are using PRIVATE mib's but i didn't add it. So that i was facing that kind of issue. Once again, Thanks for your reply guys.